# Basic operations with arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, operations

I am working in a personalized Math class, I intend to implement basic operations methods so that they add, subtract, multiply or divide in a simple way without having to be calling the operators `+ - * /` every time.

```
    public class XMath
    {
        public static double Sum(params double[] values)
        {
            double result = 0;

            if (values.Length < 1 || values is null) result = 0;
            else if (values.Length == 1) result = values[0];
            else foreach (double value in values) result += value;

            return result;
        }

        public static double Subtract(params double[] values)
        {
            double result = 0;

            if (values.Length < 1 || values is null) result = 0;
            else if (values.Length == 1) result = values[0];
            else foreach (double value in values) result -= value;

            return result;
        }

        public static double Multiply(params double[] values)
        {
            double result = 0;

            if (values.Length < 1 || values is null) result = 0;
            else if (values.Length == 1) result = values[0];
            else foreach (double value in values) result *= value;

            return result;
        }

        public static double Divide(params double[] values)
        {
            double result = 0;

            if (values.Length < 1 || values is null) result = 0;
            else if (values.Length == 1) result = values[0];
            else foreach (double value in values) result /= value;

            return result;
        }
    }
```

My problem is that the Sum method works perfectly, but the others they throw wrong results

> So, if **+=** it works, because **-=**, ***=** and **/=** no

Comment: What do you mean when you say they don't work? The results are off or Exceptions are thrown?

Comment: @Vache they throw wrong results

Comment: expected behaviour vs result?

Comment: Also should add some guard against division by 0

Comment: On these lines: `if (values.Length < 1 || values is null)` you should revers the order of those checks. That line will throw an exception when the 2nd part of the condition is true, because the 1st part will fail before the 2nd part is checked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem is that you initialize your `result` variable with 0.

Assume the array `double[] values = new [] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 }`, your `Sum` method computes `0 + 1 + 2 + 3`, `Subtract` computes `0 - 1 - 2 - 3`, `Multiply` computes `0 * 1 * 2 * 3` etc.

The extra 0 makes no difference for the sum, but it affects the other operations.

You should initialize your operations with the first element of the array instead of 0.

You can also look into the [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) method which would simplify your code to

```
values.Aggregate((x, y) => x + y);
// ...
values.Aggregate((x, y) => x - y);
// ...
values.Aggregate((x, y) => x * y);
// ...
values.Aggregate((x, y) => x / y);
```

Comment: Well, this creates an IEnumerable, so to get a result I must use a for cycle or something like that?

Comment: `Aggregate` uses an `IEnumerable` (and arrays are `IEnumerable`) but creates a `double` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

This is one instance where a for loop would be better than a foreach loop

```
    public static double Sum(params double[] values)
    {
        if (values.Length < 1 || values is null) 
           return 0;
        double result = values[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
           result += values[i];
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: The result is good but you are modifying the original array which might lead to unexpected results for the caller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enumerable.Aggregate<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TSource, TSource>)` form `System.Linq`

Aggregate uses an `IEnumerable` but creates a `double` in your case.

Example (and arrays are `IEnumerable`):

```
using System.Linq;

double[] values = new [] {5, 9, 3};

values.Aggregate((x, y) => x + y);
```